# angularjs: using $watch in directive to call serivce

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am creating a directive that does a two day binding with an input box.

a $watch is placed inside link function(which i don't know if this is a good idea) to watch the value in the input box.

it looks like the scope.$watch is not doing anything at all.

I can't figure out what the problem is as i have tried to replace 
from

```
scope.$watch('var',srv.doStuff(),true);
```

to

```
scope.$watch('location',srv.doStuff(),true);
```

No luck still.

Thanks all

http://plnkr.co/edit/4XUqPsCLFOoJD0BPlk14

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
    Input: <input type="text" ng-model="location" required><br/>
</form>
<div ng-mydir var="location"></div>
<div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.location="empty";
});

// a service 
app.service('srv', function() {
  //a function does stuff
  this.doStuff=function (){
     console.log('i am done');
  };
});


//a diretive calls serivce
app.directive('ngMydir', function (srv) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        var:'='
    },
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs,ctrl){
    console.log(scope.var);
    scope.$watch('var',srv.doStuff(),true);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed in `srv.doStuff()`, which is a function call rather than an actually function, you can use one of the following solutions:

Warp the function call `srv.doStuff()` in a function like this

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    scope.$watch('var', function () {
        srv.doStuff();
    }, true);
}
```

Or simply

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    scope.$watch('var', srv.doStuff, true);
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but i don't understand as srv.soStuff() is a function already, why do i have to wrap it inside a function?

Comment: @user2213606 updated. you did `srv.doStuff()`, this is function call rather than a function reference.